# Get Steam inventory

Tags: php, json, steam

I want to see inventory of user in site. I'm get function to get inventory CS:GO:

```
function getInventory($steamapi, $steamid, $userid) {
 }

$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$steamapi&steamids=$steamid";
$json_object = file_get_contents($url);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);

$str = $json_decoded->response->players[0]->steamid;

$urlInv = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/" . $str . "/inventory/json/730/2/?trading=1";

$json_object_inv = file_get_contents($urlInv);
$json_decoded_inv = json_decode($json_object_inv, true);

$rgInventory = $json_decoded_inv[rgInventory];
$rgInventory = array_values($rgInventory);

$rgDesc = $json_decoded_inv[rgDescriptions];
$rgDesc = array_values($rgDesc);

$itemnames = array();

*******
}}
```

When I use this, I have this trouble:

> Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ***\functions.php on line 278 //this 20 string
>
> Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ***\functions.php on line 281 //this 23 string

What is it?

Answer (score -1):

json_decode returns null if the decode fails : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php